# Select and where from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I m new to use SQL and i need to know (please) if that is possible and how so :

```
Table 1(items) : t1_id, item_name 
Table 2(parent item relation or related items) : t2_id, t1.id, t1parent.id
table 3(citie+items relation) : t3_id, t1_id, t3_cityname
```

i need to make query to get all items with the same parent and the same city .
PS the parent item got no city.

some exemple :)

in `table 1`(items) i have item1 = Project1 and item2= Task1 and item3 = Task2 Item4= Project2 item4 = Task4 ...

in `table` 2 ihave (t1parent.id = Project1 and t1.id = Task1) (t1parent.id = Project1 and t1.id = Task2) (t1parent.id = Project2 and t1.id = Task4)...

in `table 3` i have (t1_id=Task1 City=Paris) (t1_id=Task2 City=Paris) (t1_id=Task3 City=Lyon)

i need to get list of all tasks in pairs  from the `project1` (`task1` and `task2`)

Comment: "*...the same parent and the same city*" - same as what?

Comment: the same city name ... i mean 2 conditions 1- all items have the same parent and same city name. Sorry about my english

Comment: I don't understand what the difference is between `t1.id` and `t1parent.id`.

Comment: Perhaps some sample data together with the expected output would help to illustrate your requirement?

Comment: ok in table 1(items) i have item1 = Project1 and item2= Task1 and item3 = Task2 Item4= Project2 item4 = Task4 ... in table 2 ihave (t1parent.id = Project1 and t1.id = Task1) (t1parent.id = Project1 and t1.id = Task2) (t1parent.id = Project2 and t1.id = Task4)... 

in the table 3 i have (t1_id=Task1 City=Paris) (t1_id=Task2 City=Paris) (t1_id=Task3 City=Lyon)

i need to get list of all tasks in paris  from the project1 (task1 and task2)

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple JOINs to a single from table in a query, so select A.a, B.b, C.c from A JOIN B on (A.idx = B.aidx), JOIN C on (A.idx = C.aidx). You might also use WHERE to match the relevant values. In either case, where you refer to t1_id you'll want a prefix of the table name so it is clear which ti_id you're talking about.